# How does a Bugzilla server work?

Tags: client, bugzilla

We have Bugzilla installed on a computer which we would like to act as a server. I have yet to install Bugzilla on my computer, the client. Can you point me to some references which describes how Bugzilla works as a server? What I would like to do is file bugs from client computers and this will be reflected to the Bugzilla server. How do we access the Bugzilla server? Is it a requirement that all of the clients has the Bugzilla software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bugzilla is a web based application. You don't need to install anything on the clients. See [here](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/using.html) for instructions on using Bugzilla.