# How will the client access the Bugzilla server?

Tags: networking, client, bugzilla

I have just installed Bugzilla on my laptop and I will be the Bugzilla server. I would like to know how my team mates will be able to access the Bugzilla server? I know that Apache is the web server but can you point me to a reference on how clients can access the server? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users will use a web browser and point it at the IP address or your laptop or the DNS name if your company has a DNS entry for your laptop.

Comment: what will they type in the address bar to access the server?

Comment: we tried it but it did not work.. we turned off both of our windows firewall just to make sure but my team mate was not able to access the server.

Comment: Ok, now we're troubleshooting. 
 - What error message does your teammate get?
 - Can your teammate connect to just the Apache server on your laptop? I mean just the main docroot, not the bugzilla URL.
 - Can your teammate ping your laptop?
 - Do you have access logs from Apache during the time your tried to connect?

Answer (score 1):

use the link given to you on a previous [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896616/how-does-a-bugzilla-server-work) question you asked.  Also, here is a link to their [administration](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.4/en/html/administration.html) document page.